# Yarn Resource manager not utilising entire cluster resources

Tags: hadoop-yarn

We recently moved the Yarn resource manager daemon to a cloud machine from a static machine. Same configurations are being used. yarn-site.xml and capacity-scheduler.xml as earlier with the machine name change included.

Rest of the cluster is a mix of both static and cloud machines.
  The resource manager UI shows all nodes as live and available capacity of memory and vcores is accurately reported.

```
root.default stats: default: capacity=0.9,
 absoluteCapacity=0.9, 
 usedResources=<memory:12288, vCores:6>
 usedCapacity=0.043290164, 
 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.038961038,
 numApps=7, 
 numContainers=6

Queue configuration details :

Queue State:    RUNNING

Used Capacity:  3.6%

Absolute Used Capacity: 3.2%

Absolute Capacity:  90.0%

Absolute Max Capacity:  95.0%

Used Resources: <memory:10240, vCores:5>

Num Schedulable Applications:   5

Num Non-Schedulable Applications:   0

Num Containers: 5

Max Applications:   9000

Max Applications Per User:  9000

Max Schedulable Applications:   29260

Max Schedulable Applications Per User:  27720

Configured Capacity:    90.0%

Configured Max Capacity:    95.0%

Configured Minimum User Limit Percent:  100%

Configured User Limit Factor:   1.0

Active users:   thirdeye <Memory: 10240 (100.00%), vCores: 5 (100.00%), Schedulable Apps: 5, Non-Schedulable Apps: 0>
```

At any point of time only 4-6 containers are being allocated. These are being allocated both on static and cloud node managers of the cluster.

What could be the reason for the under utilization of the cluster resources.

Submitted jobs are getting piled up(right now at 7K)